# How can I make my Lexmark x2480 (2400 series) printer work?

Tags: drivers, printing, lexmark

Ubuntu cannot find matching drivers and the Lexmark support website says that they do not supply Linux drivers for this model.

Comment: http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Lexmark/Lexmark-2400series This suggests that you can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no driver support for this printer... that is known from various searches online at many sites which all say "no driver support available for this printer" like me , you'll have to get another printer.